# lrange returns false instead of the list

Tags: node.js, list, redis, push

I'm trying to make my own simple Message Queue using Redis.

However, I'm having problem making a queue with Redis.

I used Redis for caching in other parts of my project so i'm sure redis connection is fine(+ I tried priting out the instance and it seems fine).

message_queue.js

```
const redis = require("./redis.js");

var sendMessage = async (queue) => {
    var result = await redis.rpush(queue,5);
    console.log(result);
    var arr = await redis.lrange(queue,0,-1);
    console.log(arr);
};
```

redis.js

```
const redis = require('redis');
const redisinfo = require('../secret/redisinfo.js');
const client = redis.createClient(redisinfo);

client.on("error",function(err){
    console.log("Error " + err);    
});

module.exports = client;
```

when i run sendMessage function from message_queue.js,
it prints false and false.

what am i doing wrong to pushing item into queue and printing it? Do I need to do something before this process such as declaring a list?

p.s.
I don't know if this is the proper method to use this package but it seems like i need to use a callback function to access the result...

this following code works as expected

```
redis.lrange(queue,0,-1,function(err,res){
    if(res.length != 0){
        console.log(`Something is in queue`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "declare" lists in Redis, RPUSH should create a list under the specified key the first time it is used.

Is it possible that you have already used the key name and stored something that is *not* a list? That would explain the behavior you are seeing. Run `DEL <key>` first in Redis to fix it, in that case.

Comment: Could you link the redis module you are using?  The `false` return value seems totally wrong to me (an RPUSH, in any lib I've used, should either return the number of elements added _or_ throw an exception).  There could be a bug in the module, or if you are using some custom wrapper, there could be a bug in the wrapper.

Comment: I figured out that if i had to use a callback function to access the result. I don't know if this is the proper way to use this but that's how i'm using it for now

Comment: Ah, makes sense - if you look at the docs in the link you posted, they provide examples of promisifying the library which would let you use promises instead of callbacks.  Alternately, instead of bluebird, you can always use node's built-in `util.promisify` on any given function.